# NetworkOnMainThreadException when used as a LaunchedEffect key

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, side-effects

When I use

```
 LaunchedEffect(Dispatchers.IO)
```

I get,

> NetworkOnMainThreadException

How should I use this function to run on background thread?

this is my code:

```
LaunchedEffect(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val input = URL("https://rezaapp.downloadseriesmovie.ir/maintxt.php").readText()
    println(input)
}
```

I'm using it inside my jetpack compose project

Comment: What are you expecting on a LaunchedEffect where a specific coroutine Dispatcher is used as its key?

Comment: I'm not pro. when we say Dispatchers.IO , aren't we saying that we want our function to run on background?

Comment: I think what your'e looking for is Coroutine `launch`, not a compose `LaunchedEffect`

Answer (score 3):

`LaunchedEffect` is one of the many [Side Effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) in Jetpack Compose, but instead of just explaining, it would be better for us to just have very simple compose use-case. Though I'm expecting that you already know what is `re-composition` and how a `MutableState` triggers it.

What we'll have:

- a screen with a button in the middle
- a `MutableState` increment-able integer value
- a Log statement inside `LaunchedEffect`

What we'll do

- click the button and increment the `MutableState` integer value
- print the incremented value

What we'll expect

- Logcat will display the value coming from `LaunchedEffect`, even before clicking the button

Our simple `Composable`

```
@Composable
fun ComposeSample() {

    var intNum by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
         Button(onClick = {
             intNum++
         }) {
             Text(
                 text = "Increment the integer"
             )
         }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        Log.e("IntNumber", "Current value: $intNum")
    }
}
```

At this point, pay attention to the `key` I supplied with the `LaunchedEffect`.

When the screen is rendered for the first time, `LaunchedEffect` will trigger and we'll see a logcat print.

```
E: Current value: 0
```

But when I click the button it doesn't show the incremented value. Because `LaunchedEffect` needs a `key` that will change if you intend to trigger it every `re-composition`.

Now I changed the `key` I supplied to `LaunchedEffect` using the `MutableState` `intNum` variable,

```
LaunchedEffect(intNum) {
    Log.e("IntNumber", "Current value: $intNum")
}
```

every click the logcat prints, because every time the `intNum` changes, the `LaunchedEffect` is triggered and triggers the Logcat statement.

```
E: Current value: 0
E: Current value: 1
E: Current value: 2
E: Current value: 3
```

When a `key` of a `LaunchedEffect` has changed and a `composition` happens, it will trigger anything inside its block.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your posted code, I don't even know how did it happen, but I suppose there aren't any use-case (to the best of my knowledge) where you will use a specific coroutine Dispatcher as a `LaunchedEffect` `key`.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at what LaunchedEffect does first. In your code, you placed `Dispatchers.IO` as the key and not as the Dispatcher to use.

Since LaunchedEffect will have a block of `CoroutineScope.() -> Unit`, you can switch thread within this block like the following :

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val input = URL("https://rezaapp.downloadseriesmovie.ir/maintxt.php").readText()
        println(input)
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give it to you straight and clear,

- `lifecyclescope`, or any `coroutine scope` in compose ui is on main
  thread by default.
- Especially for the compose coroutine scope you can not change their
  dispatcher,

I strongly suggest that you call ViewModel method and there you launch the coroutine in side `viewmodelSope`, also keep in mind that the compose coroutine scopes are for light suspending operation, **do not perform any heavy lift in those scopes.**